# Loop over data.frame columns to generate dummy variable in R

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, panel-data

I'm struggling with generating a variable for my current project. I'm using R version 4.0.1 on Windows.

### Data description

I have unbalanced panel data in a `data.table` containing 243 variables (before running the commands) and 8,278 observations. The data is uniquely identified by `ID` and `period`. Additionally, in columns `69:135` I got different region dummies (2= yes, company operates in region; 1= no, company does not operate in region) and in columns `178:244` lagged versions of the very same variables from columns `69:135` grouped by ID. Here is a small example of the data:

```
dat <- 
data.table(id = as.factor(c(rep("C001", 3), "C002", rep("C003", 5), rep("C004", 2), rep("C005", 7))),
period = as.factor(c(1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 10, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10)),
region1 = as.factor(c(NA, NA, 2, 1, NA, 1, 2, 2, 1, NA, 1, rep(NA, 7))),
region2 = as.factor(c(1, 2, 1, 1, NA, NA, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, rep(NA, 7))),
industry = as.factor(c(rep("Finance", 3), "Culture", rep("Nutrition", 5), rep("Finance", 2), rep("Medicine", 7))),
number_employees = as.numeric(c(10, 10, 12, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 18, 25, 100, 110, 108, 108, 120, 120, 120)),
lag_region1 = as.factor(c(rep(NA, 6), 1, 2, 2, rep(NA, 9))),
lag_region2 = as.factor(c(NA, 1, 2, rep(NA, 4), 2, 1, NA, 1, rep(NA, 7))))


#this gives (last 8 rows are not printed):
#      id period region1 region2  industry number_employees lag_region1 lag_region2
# 1: C001      1    <NA>       1   Finance               10        <NA>        <NA>
# 2: C001      2    <NA>       2   Finance               10        <NA>           1
# 3: C001      3       2       1   Finance               12        <NA>           2
# 4: C002      2       1       1   Culture                2        <NA>        <NA>
# 5: C003      1    <NA>    <NA> Nutrition                2        <NA>        <NA>
# 6: C003      4       1    <NA> Nutrition                4        <NA>        <NA>
# 7: C003      5       2       2 Nutrition                4           1        <NA>
# 8: C003      6       2       1 Nutrition                4           2           2
# 9: C003     10       1       2 Nutrition                4           2           1
#10: C004      3    <NA>       1   Finance               18        <NA>        <NA>
```

### Desired outcome

I want to generate a new dummy variable `left_region` which equals "yes" when a company has left at least one region in the respective period. I wanted to approach this issue by "comparing" column 69 to column 178, 70 to 179, 71 to 180, etc. `left_region` should be set to "yes" if e.g. `dt[, 69] == 1 & dt[, 178] == 2` (so, `left_region`equals "yes" if a company leaves a region it was operating in before). The desired result looks like this:

```
# desired result (last 8 rows are not printed):
#      id period region1 region2  industry number_employees lag_region1 lag_region2 left_region
# 1: C001      1    <NA>       1   Finance               10        <NA>        <NA>          no
# 2: C001      2    <NA>       2   Finance               10        <NA>           1          no
# 3: C001      3       2       1   Finance               12        <NA>           2         yes
# 4: C002      2       1       1   Culture                2        <NA>        <NA>          no
# 5: C003      1    <NA>    <NA> Nutrition                2        <NA>        <NA>          no
# 6: C003      4       1    <NA> Nutrition                4        <NA>        <NA>          no
# 7: C003      5       2       2 Nutrition                4           1        <NA>          no
# 8: C003      6       2       1 Nutrition                4           2           2         yes
# 9: C003     10       1       2 Nutrition                4           2           1         yes
#10: C004      3    <NA>       1   Finance               18        <NA>        <NA>          no
```

### Problem description

I'm struggling to get this running for all observations at once though. I tried it using `ifelse()` in a `for`loop. For this to work I had to make my `data.table`a `data.frame`first.

```
# generate empty cells
df <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = 8278, ncol = 67))
# combine prior data.table and new data.frame in large data.frame (with data.table the following loop does not work)
dt <- as.data.frame(cbind(dt, df))

# loop through 67 columns comparing 69 to 178, 70 to 179, etc.
for (i in 69:135) {
 dt[, i + 176] <- ifelse(is.na(dt[, i]) & is.na(dt[, (i + 109)]), NA,
         ifelse(dt[, i] == 1 & dt[, (i + 109)] == 2, "yes", "no"
         )
  )
}

# generate final dummy variable left_region --> there is some error here
dt$left_region <-
  ifelse(any(dt[, c(245:311)] == "yes"), "yes", "no")
```

Running the last `ifelse()` in combination with `any()`, however, leads to `left_region`containing only "yes" for every of the 8,278 oberservations.

I tested how the latter `ifelse()` command behaves if using only one observation.

```
#take out one observation
one_row <- dt[7, ]

library(dplyr)
# generate left_region for one observation only
new <- 
  one_row %>%
  mutate(left_region = ifelse(any(one_row[, c(245:311)] == "yes"), "yes", "no"))
```

The picked observation should generate `left_region`== "no" but it does the opposite in this case. It seems that somehow the last `ifelse()`argument "no" is not registered by R.

Aside from not being a "pretty" solution to the problem neither putting the combination of `ifelse()`and `any()` into a `for()` loop solves the issue. In this case `left_region` only takes on "yes" in 270 cases but still never "no".

```
for (i in 1:nrow(dt)) {
  dt$left_region[i] <-
    ifelse(any(dt[i, c(245:311)] == "yes"), "yes", "no")
}
```

**Does anyone know why this happens? What do I need to do in order to receive my desired result? Any idea is highly appreciated!**

I very much hope that I managed to explain everything in an easily understandable manner.
Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: does this give you all yeses? `dt$left_region <- ifelse(rowSums(dt[, c(245:311)] == 'yes') > 0, 'yes', 'no')`

Comment: @rawr thanks for the suggestion but it gives me NAs only

Comment: @rawr turns out I had to include ``na.rm = T`` meaning ```dt$left_region <- ifelse(rowSums(dt[, c(245:311)] == 'yes', na.rm = T) > 0, 'yes', 'no')```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dt[, 69:135] == 1` will return `TRUE` if the value in column 69:135 is 1 and `FALSE` otherwise.

`dt[, 178:244] == 2` will return `TRUE` if the value in column 178:244 is 2 and `FALSE` otherwise.

You can perform an AND (`&`) operation between them to compare them elementwise meaning `dt[, 69] & dt[, 178]`, `dt[, 70] & dt[, 179]` and so on. Take rowwise sum of them and mark it as `'Yes'` even if a single `TRUE` is found in that row.

```
dt$left_region <- ifelse(rowSums(dt[, 69:135] == 1 & dt[, 178:244] == 2) > 0, 'yes', 'no')
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, Ronak. It gives me ``NA``s only though. Further, I feel that ```dt[, 69:135] == 1 & dt[, 178:244] == 2``` is not looking at the required columns elementwise (meaning ``dt[, 69] & dt[, 178]``, ``dt[, 70] & dt[, 179]`` as you already indicated).

Comment: It is looking at the data elementwise :) You might have `NA`s in your data. Try : `dt$left_region <- ifelse(rowSums(dt[, 69:135] == 1 & dt[, 178:244] == 2, na.rm = TRUE) > 0, 'yes', 'no')`

Comment: Wow.. Often, solutions can be embarrassingly easy. THANKS a lot, Ronak! Seems I didn't quite get how ``na.rm`` works until now. Thought it would also remove the ``NA``s of the variable I'm about to generate.